# How to block external access to register_rest_route callback?

Tags: rest-api

I'm creating a new API route that allows me to update a plugin database entries on custom table from an external application (below the code). My code seems to work, but I need an advice on how to block requests that don't belong to my app, in order to prevent an arbitrary user that discovers the route and knows for example how to use postman could edit the database. I was thinking to put `get_http_origin()` on the top of the `register_rest_route` callback function, comparing the origin of the request with a fixed string I know being the legitimate application. Will it work? Is there a more proficient/correct method?

```
class Rate_My_Post_Custom_API {
    public function __construct () {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'create_update_rating_route' ) );
    }

    public function create_update_rating_route () {
        register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'update-rmp', array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => function ( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
                global $wpdb;
                
                $request_body = json_decode( $request -> get_body() );
                $rating_table = $wpdb -> prefix . "rmp_analytics";
                $total_votes = get_post_meta( $request_body -> post_id, 'rmp_vote_count', true ) ? intval( get_post_meta( $request_body -> post_id, 'rmp_vote_count', true ) ) : 0;
                $new_votes = $total_votes + 1;
                $ratings_sum = get_post_meta( $request_body -> post_id, 'rmp_rating_val_sum', true ) ? intval( get_post_meta( $request_body -> post_id, 'rmp_rating_val_sum', true ) ) : 0;
                $new_ratings_sum = $ratings_sum + $request_body -> vote;
                $new_average = round( ( $new_ratings_sum / $new_votes ), 1 );

                update_post_meta( $request_body -> post_id, 'rmp_vote_count', $new_votes );
                update_post_meta( $request_body -> post_id, 'rmp_rating_val_sum', $new_ratings_sum );

                $rating_updated = $wpdb -> insert( $rating_table, array(
                    'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
                    'ip' => '-1',
                    'country' => '0',
                    'user' => $request_body -> user_id,
                    'post' => $request_body -> post_id,
                    'action' => '1',
                    'duration' => '1',
                    'average' => $new_average,
                    'votes' => $new_votes,
                    'value' => $request_body -> vote,
                    'token' => '-1',
                ) );

                if ( $rating_updated ) :
                    return rest_ensure_response( 'New rating registered.' );
                else :
                    return rest_ensure_response( 'Error in registering rating.' );  
                endif;
            },
            'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
        ) );
    }
}
new Rate_My_Post_Custom_API();
```

Comment: _you can't hide this route_, anybody who looks at the network panel will see what you did and be able to reproduce it, and the REST API itself will advertise the route. At a minimum try to put a nonce on it but the access control you're asking about doesn't exist, and makes no sense when you really think about how it works and how URLs and webpages work

Comment: Also: `return rest_ensure_response( 'Error in registering rating.' );` will show as a successful response, you should use `return WP_Error( 'Error registering rating' )`, you're also doing a pointless `json_decode`, you don't need the `request_body` variable, just do `$request['post_id']`, all the parameters are accessible on `$request` as if it were an array. You also don't need your callback to be an inline function, it will happily accept `array( $this, 'rest_route )`. Fundamentally though, your situation is worse than you realised, as the user can refresh the page and re-vote

Comment: @TomJNowell the codex says ```rest_ensure_response``` is designed to manage the errors too. Am I wrong? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_ensure_response/

Comment: if you pass a `WP_Error` to `rest_ensure_response` yes, but you've passed it a string. If you did pass it an error object, it would return that error object, otherwise it creates a `WP_Rest_Response` object. What you've done ensures a HTTP 200 response, _even when an error occurs_.

Comment: additionally, the REST API itself calls `rest_ensure_response` on what you returned, so if you call it yourself it will get called multiple times. If you have an error you should return an error, not a plain string that says there's a problem. Because of this, modern HTTP request javascript libraries won't trigger `.error` or `.catch` etc on promises such as when you use `fetch()` or the jQuery `get`/`post` etc, so you'd have to implement the error checking all yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When registering a route with `register_rest_route()` you can provide a `permission_callback` which is a function that checks whether the user has permission to use the endpoint. If only Administrator users should be able to use the endpoint then you can check for the `manage_options` capability in the callback, like this:

```
register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', 'update-rmp'', array(
    'permission_callback' => function () {
        return current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
    },
) );
```

**Note:** Do not use `wp/v2` as the namespace. That namespace is for endpoints registered by WordPress itself. Third party themes and plugins should use their own namespace.

To make your API request as a user with the required privileges, sign in as that user and go to *Users > Profile*  and look for the *Application Passwords* section. Add a new application password and copy the result. You can now use this password from your application using Basic Authentication:

```
curl --user "USERNAME:PASSWORD" -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/myplugin/v1/update-rmp
```

Just substitute `USERNAME` with your WordPress username, and `PASSWORD` with the application password.

Answer (score 1):

wordpress broadcasts the available routes everywhere, and in any case hidding it is a weak security measure. Depending on how sensative the information, and how easy it is for a bad actor to wiretap the communication between the app and server you have two options

1. If you just want to avoid low level attacks, use a "API KEY" which will identify that it is your app and not just a random "postman"
2. Encript the content of the message.

Even 2 will not do much to deter a sophisticated attacker if you store the encryption key as part of your code, and you will need to store it in a more secure storage on the app's device. You might have to have a login step and pass whatever keys in it.

hmmm.... not much actually related to wordpress here, if this is very important and not just a problem that nags you for completeness of your solution, you should probably ask in security oriented sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'update-rmp', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => function ( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
        // callback logic goes here
    },
    'permission_callback' => function () {
        $origin = get_http_origin();
        $expected_origin = 'https://example.com';
        if ( $origin === $expected_origin ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
) );
```

You can also use the is_user_logged_in() function in conjunction with a nonce to check if the user is logged in and the nonce is correct before allowing access to the route.